# Kafka broker with "No space left on device"

Tags: apache-kafka

I have a 6 node Kafka cluster where due to unforseen circumstances the kafka partition on one of the brokers filled up completely.

Kafka understandable won't start.

We managed to process the data from topics on the other brokers.

We have a replication factor of 4 so all is good there.

Can I delete an index file from a topic manually so that kafka can start and clear the data itself or is there a risk of corruption if I do that?

Once the brokers starts it should clear most of the space as we have cleared the topics by setting the retention low on the topics that have been processed.

What is the best approach?

Comment: You can delete the logs, yes, assuming the other replicas are in sync. The better approach would be to increase the disk size

Comment: Hi @cricket_007 is it best to delete an index, log file or the whole directory?

Comment: I think by logs @cricket_007 meant Kafka logs. Not anything that is related to Kafka indices. If your Kafka environment has been up and running for a long time then you may have lots of logs that can be removed.

Comment: You can tune, highly consume topic by lowering retention policy

Answer (score 1):

The best way that I found, in this case, is removing logs and decrease the `retention` or `replication` of Kafka!

Answer (score 0):

Some comments mention tuning the retention. I mentioned that we had already done that. The problem was that the broker that had a full disk could not start until some space was cleared.

After testing on dev environment I was able to resolve this by deleting some .log and .index files from one Kafka log folder. This allowed the broker to start. It then automatically started to clear the data based on retention and the situation was resolved.